# error in java (CameraMIDlet)

Tags: java-me

i have the following code which is giving me error:

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException;
import javax.bluetooth.DeviceClass;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryListener;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.ServiceRecord;
import javax.bluetooth.UUID;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.List;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletStateChangeException;


public class DeviceClientCOMM implements DiscoveryListener, CommandListener {

    static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    static final String DEBUG_address = "0013FDC157C8"; // N6630

    protected UUID uuid = new UUID(0x1101); // serial port profile

    protected int inquiryMode = DiscoveryAgent.GIAC; // no pairing is needed

    protected int connectionOptions = ServiceRecord.NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT;

    protected int stopToken = 255;

    private Command backCommand = new Command("Back", Command.BACK, 1);
    protected Form infoArea = new Form("Bluetooth Client");
    protected Vector deviceList = new Vector();
  private CameraMIDlet mymidlet;
    private byte[] imag;

    public DeviceClientCOMM(CameraMIDlet m, byte[] imag) {
        mymidlet = m;
        this.imag = imag;
        infoArea.setCommandListener(this);
        infoArea.addCommand(backCommand);
        try {
            startApp();
        } catch (MIDletStateChangeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {

        makeInformationAreaGUI();

        if (DEBUG) // skip inquiry in debug mode
        {
            startServiceSearch(new RemoteDevice(DEBUG_address) {
            });
        } else {
            try {
                startDeviceInquiry();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                log(t);
            }
        }
    }

    private void startDeviceInquiry() {
        try {
            log("Start inquiry method - this will take few seconds...");
            DiscoveryAgent agent = getAgent();
            agent.startInquiry(inquiryMode, this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log(e);
        }
    }

    public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
        log("A device discovered (" + getDeviceStr(btDevice) + ")");
        deviceList.addElement(btDevice);
    }

    public void inquiryCompleted(int discType) {
        log("Inquiry compeleted. Please select device from combo box.");
        makeDeviceSelectionGUI();
    }

    private void startServiceSearch(RemoteDevice device) {
        try {
            log("Start search for Serial Port Profile service from " + getDeviceStr(device));
            UUID uuids[] = new UUID[]{uuid};
            getAgent().searchServices(null, uuids, device, this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log(e);
        }
    }

    public void servicesDiscovered(int transId, ServiceRecord[] records) {
        log("Service discovered.");
        for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            ServiceRecord rec = records[i];
            String url = rec.getConnectionURL(connectionOptions, false);
            handleConnection(url);
        }
    }

    public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {
        String msg = null;
        switch (respCode) {
            case SERVICE_SEARCH_COMPLETED:
                msg = "the service search completed normally";
                break;
            case SERVICE_SEARCH_TERMINATED:
                msg = "the service search request was cancelled by a call to DiscoveryAgent.cancelServiceSearch()";
                break;
            case SERVICE_SEARCH_ERROR:
                msg = "an error occurred while processing the request";
                break;
            case SERVICE_SEARCH_NO_RECORDS:
                msg = "no records were found during the service search";
                break;
            case SERVICE_SEARCH_DEVICE_NOT_REACHABLE:
                msg = "the device specified in the search request could not be reached or the local device could not establish a connection to the remote device";
                break;
        }
        log("Service search completed - " + msg);
    }

    private void handleConnection(final String url) {
        Thread echo = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                StreamConnection stream = null;
                InputStream in = null;
                OutputStream out = null;

                try {
                    log("Connecting to server by url: " + url);
                    stream = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(url);

                    log("Bluetooth stream open.");
                    //   InputStream in = stream.openInputStream();
                    out = stream.openOutputStream();
                    in = stream.openInputStream();
                    startReadThread(in);
                    // String stringImage = Base64.encode(imag);
                    log("Start echo loop.");
                    out.write(imag);
                    out.flush();
                //       out.flush();

                //   stream.close();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log(e);
                } finally {
                    log("Bluetooth stream closed.");
                    if (out != null) {
                        try {

                            out.close();
                            stream.close();

                            logSet("Image Transfer done\n----------------\n\nWaiting for results...");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            log(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        echo.start();
    }

    private void startReadThread(final InputStream in) {

        Thread reader = new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                byte[] s = new byte[512];
                //boolean flag = true;
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        int r = in.read(s);

                        if (r != -1) {

                            logSet(new String(s, 0, r));
                        }  else {
                            break;
                        }


                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    log(e);

                } finally {
                    if (in != null) {
                        try {
                            in.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        reader.start();
    }

    private void makeInformationAreaGUI() {
        infoArea.deleteAll();
        Display.getDisplay(mymidlet).setCurrent(infoArea);
    }

    private void makeDeviceSelectionGUI() {
        final List devices = new List("Select a device", List.IMPLICIT);
        for (int i = 0; i < deviceList.size(); i++) {
            devices.append(
                    getDeviceStr((RemoteDevice) deviceList.elementAt(i)), null);
        }
        devices.setCommandListener(new

              CommandListener(   ) {

    public  void commandAction(Command arg0,
        Displayable arg1)
        {
                makeInformationAreaGUI();
                startServiceSearch((RemoteDevice) deviceList.elementAt(devices.getSelectedIndex()));
            }
        });
        Display.getDisplay(mymidlet).setCurrent(devices);
    }

    synchronized private void log(String msg) {
        infoArea.append(msg);
        infoArea.append("\n\n");
    }

    synchronized private void logSet(String msg) {
        infoArea.deleteAll();
        infoArea.append(msg);
        infoArea.append("\n\n");

    }

    private void log(Throwable e) {
        log(e.getMessage());
    }

    private DiscoveryAgent getAgent() {
        try {
            return LocalDevice.getLocalDevice().getDiscoveryAgent();
        } catch (BluetoothStateException e) {
            throw new Error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private String getDeviceStr(RemoteDevice btDevice) {
        return getFriendlyName(btDevice) + " - 0x" + btDevice.getBluetoothAddress();
    }

    private String getFriendlyName(RemoteDevice btDevice) {
        try {
            return btDevice.getFriendlyName(false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "no name available";
        }
    }

    public void commandAction(Command arg0, Displayable arg1) {
        mymidlet.DisplayMainList();
    }
}
```

the errors are

C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\DeviceClientCOMM\src\DeviceClientCOMM.java:51: cannot find symbol

symbol  : class CameraMIDlet

location: class DeviceClientCOMM
  private CameraMIDlet mymidlet;

C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\DeviceClientCOMM\src\DeviceClientCOMM.java:54: cannot find symbol

symbol  : class CameraMIDlet

location: class DeviceClientCOMM
    public DeviceClientCOMM(CameraMIDlet m, byte[] imag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an import for `CameraMIDlet`, so the compiler doesn't know which class you mean.

Assuming you've got an appropriate classpath entry, you should just be able to add the right import and it should be fine.

Are you sure `CameraMIDlet` exists for your use though? I can see some *sample* code in JSR-135, but I'm not sure it's a full API to be used...

Comment: thank you for reply.can you help me out to understand bluetooth based streaming on mobile phone?

Comment: @user243680: I'm afraid not - I know nothing about that.